# **identifier msqid is removed from the system** meaning

Tags: c, message-queue

My program was giving me an identifier removed error. I was going through the man page and I didn't understand what could cause this error "identifier removed". I've noticed that this happens everytime I try to send a message for the second time to a user process. The first time sending and recieving is fine. I tried a lot to reproduce a small example but I'm unable to. I don't think anyone here wants to go over so many lines of code. But basically what I am doing is

```
while(1)
{
      if(messsage recieved from oss)  //msg type getpid(), message text stores master pid
       {
          send message to oss  //message type master pid, message text stores getpid()
       }
}
```

the user process gets sent a message at random times like: time 1, time 4, time 8 etc. 
The first time it sends and recieves its fine.

Comment: The error is actually from user process. It says "Error in receiving message from master(I typed this part): Identifier removed".

Answer (score 1):

`Identifier removed` is the error message corresponding to error `EIDRM`. My system's man page for `msgrcv` says this error is returned for the following reason:

> While the process was sleeping to receive a message, the message queue was removed.

A message queue is removed by passing command `IPC_RMID` to `msgctl`.

Comment: How do I pass the control to master while the user process sleeps? I think what is happening now is, the user is blocked and the master is not running, eventually the signal alarm (10seconds) causes the master to do cleanup. In the cleanup function the message queue is freed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that question, and the comments is not the place to ask new questions (because it leads to such poor questions as "How do I pass the control to master while the user process sleeps?")